# Check if d has variable in function (d) {...} in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating an array of objects to create a legend in D3. Some of these objects will have specific variables, whereas other objects won't have these variables. Instead they should simply use the default value.

How do I check whether the variable `d.text` exists? I'd like to do that instead of having empty strings in all my objects that uses the default value.

```
    var size_link_data = [{
                percentage : 0.5,
                roundoff : 2,
                recordType: 0,
                text: "a calls b the most"
            }, {
                percentage : 0.5,
                roundoff : 2,
                recordType: 1,
                text: ""
            }, {
                percentage : 0.3,
                roundoff : 1,
                recordType: 1,
                text: ""
            },
            {
                percentage : 0.1,
                roundoff : 1,
                recordType: 1,
                text: ""
            }
        ]

...

legened_next_section.append('text')
    .attr('x', 35)
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
            return i * 20;          })
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.text != ""? d.text : d.percentage;
    })
    .style('fill', '#757575');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check to see if the property has been defined. If it has, it will use the `text` property, otherwise it will default to the `percentage`.

```
.text(function (d) {
    return typeof(d.text) !== "undefined" ? d.text : d.percentage;
})
```

In the example below, `typeof(size_link_data[0].text)` will be `string` whereas `typeof(size_link_data[1].text)` will return `undefined`.

```
var size_link_data = [{
            percentage : 0.5,
            roundoff : 2,
            recordType: 0,
            text: "a calls b the most"
        }, {
            percentage : 0.5,
            roundoff : 2,
            recordType: 1
            //No 'text' property
        }
    ];
```